# Replication is slow after upgrading from mysql 5.6.17 to mariadb 10.6.12

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.6, mariadb-10.6

I was using mysql 5.6.17 and upgraded to mariadb 10.6.12 due to EOS.

- After installing mariadb on the same server, change the basedir to run mariadb.
- After that, I ran the mariadb-upgrade tool to complete the upgrade.

However, after upgrading to mariadb, the speed of the replication slave became significantly slower.

Using mysql 5.6.17, there is a delay of up to 10 minutes compared to master when running Replication SLAVE, but when using the
In the case of mariadb 10.6.12, there is a delay of about 20 minutes or more.

- Tested with a server with the same specifications.

We used the same my.cnf settings as in 5.6.17 and configured the
In the case of table structure, one particular table has a capacity of about 150GB or more without partitioning.

- Replication delay occurs when INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE occurs in that table.

I tried increasing the value of slave_parallel_workers from 0 to 2, but it didn't have much effect because the capacity of one table is huge.

Are there any guides or things I should be checking?

Comment: Additional DB information request from MariaDB srvr, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Perhaps the most significant is "binlog format".

Comment: unclear whether you upgraded the primary, the replica, or both?